# postfix redirect mail to transport going round relayhost

Tags: email, postfix, relay

I have worked correctly postfix with this setting:

main.cf

```
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
relayhost = [not.exist.dom]:555
```

relayhost_map

```
# postmap hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
@my.sender.exemple1.com [my.reley.hos1]:7454
@my.sender.exemple2.com [my.reley.hos2]:7454
@my.sender.exemple3.com [my.reley.hos3]:7454
@my.sender.exemple4.com [my.reley.hos4]:7454
```

transport

```
#   postmap /etc/postfix/transport
transpostfix1@localhost.localhost   emailport4:
transpostfix2@localhost.localhost   emailsport2:
transpostfix3@localhost.localhost   emailtransport1:
# with this sender_dependent_relayhost_maps not work
# *   newtransport:
```

Question:
How to replace destination **relayhost = [not.exist.dom]:555** to new destination **newtransport**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) update postfix from 2.66 to 3.1

2) add to main.cf

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relaytransport_map
default_transport = newtransport:
```

3) /etc/postfix/relaytransport_map

```
# postmap /etc/postfix/relaytransport_map
@exemple133.com smtp:
@exemple12.ua   smtp:
@exemple1.com   smtp:
*   newtransport:
```